# How to item in list view and display a new GUI in another page which shows description?

Tags: android

[image]

```
String[] price ={
        "RM9.50",
        "RM6.50",
        "RM10.80",
        "RM80.20",
        "RM100.60",
        "RM50.10",
        "RM12.30",
        "RM90.50"
};
    String[] itemname ={
            "Safari",
            "Camera",
            "Global",
            "FireFox",
            "UC Browser",
            "Android Folder",
            "VLC Player",
            "Cold War"
    };

Integer[] imgid={
        R.drawable.pic1,
        R.drawable.pic2,
        R.drawable.pic3,
        R.drawable.pic4,
        R.drawable.pic5,
        R.drawable.pic6,
        R.drawable.pic7,
        R.drawable.pic8,
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(this, itemname, imgid, price);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);




    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String Slecteditem = itemname[+position];
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Slecteditem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}  //main actiivty
```

This is the custom list adapter that the main function call. The code shows a list of all the item. However i want to click into one of the list item to display a new page with a more detail description. The first picture shows the list view, the second picture is a more detail description.

```
public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemname, Integer[] imgid, String[] price) {
    super(context, R.layout.mylist, itemname);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.context=context;
    this.itemname=itemname;
    this.imgid=imgid;
    this.price=price;
}

public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null,true);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
    extratxt.setText(price[position]);
    return rowView;

};
```

}

Comment: You can start a new activity in the on click listener and then pass the identifier of the particular image through the intent..

Answer (score 0):

You can override the method onListItemClick and start a new class.You can also pass data to new Activity using putExtra()

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
 if (position == appropriate_condition) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
 }
}
```